# I can't change my RGB colour into grayscale images in python using CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So, I am doing this project to detect diabetic retinopathy using deep learning. I however am stuck in the preprocessing image section as the pictures that are in different folders(for diff stages of DR) wouldn't convert into grayscale nomatter how much I try.

Here is my functions that does the early preprocessing stage:

```
def preprocessing(conditionname,directory):
  for image in os.listdir(directory):
    label = eye_label(conditionname,image)
    path = os.path.join(directory,image)
    image = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #Reading the colour images
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Changing coloured image into black and white
    #image = cv2.addWeighted(image,10,cv2.GaussianBlur(image , (0,0) , sigma_x) ,-4 ,12) 
    image = cv2.resize(image,(image_size,image_size)) #Changing the size of each image
    return image
```

Comment: Try inspecting `image.shape` after each operation to see if the number of channels or x-y dimensions has changed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Can you give me more info in this if possible?

Comment: I would also like to add that when I call the preprocessing function, it does give me the matrix of 0's and 1's which tells me that it has been transformed into grayscale. However when I use matplotlib to see the image, it prints the colour image.

array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

Comment: The matplotlib code you didn't show is the problem! Try adding `cmap='gray'`

Comment: Apologies. The code is:

import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread(sample_healthy)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

Comment: II tried adding cmap but it's still showing coloured images

Comment: Rather than put updates and code in the comments area where it is unformatted and difficult to read, please click `edit` below your question and make sure your code and question are up to date and complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your debugger or IDE to check everything gives you the result you expect, one step at a time.

If you load an image, print its shape:

```
img = cv2.imread(...)
print(image.shape)
```

If you convert an image to greyscale, check it has 1 channel afterwards:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(...)
print(image.shape)
```

If you resize an image, check its size is what you expect:

```
img = cv2.resize(...)
print(image.shape)
```

If you are going to return an image from a function, check its size and type:

```
print(result.shape, result.dtype)
return result
```